# Fast way to find smallest n so that for X <= n*n

Tags: c

Sorry for the poor title. I couldn't find a better title. (Edits are welcome :p )

Lets say that there is a number X=8. I know 2*2=4 so it does not contain the number 8.

**EDIT: imagine a 2x2 grid ... 1,2,3,4 ... it does not contain 8**

Now, 3*3 = 9 and we have found our winner(n=3)!

My (poor) code for this purpose

```
 long long int i=0; N = 8;
 while (i*i <N)
    {
        i++;
    }
    l = i; // l is to store he number "3"; say 8 is in a 3x3 grid
```

This is not a efficient way to calculate when N = 100000000.

What is more efficient way to get i*i that contains X ?

Comment: What do you mean by "4 so it does not contain the number 8"? Do you mean "4 is a divisor of 8"?

Comment: How does 9 contain 8? You mean to find the smallest square number that is larger than or equal to some input number?

Comment: 8 is bigger than 4 .... imagine a 2x2 grid... it will have 1,2,3,4 cells.... but for the cell 8 i need 3x3 grid... that will give me 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ... :)

Comment: Isn't it what Shahbaz suggested? Smallest integer N with N*N >= X?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `sqrt` function from `<math.h>`. It'll be a (fairly) efficient algorithm, and should run much faster than your loop. Then round up, and you have your answer.

```
int find_containing_int(double x)
{
  const double sqr = sqrt(x);

  return ceil(sqr);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to link/compile with `-lm`.